# Linux cronjob doesn't work (execute script)

Tags: linux, scripting, shell, cron

I created a cronjob with the command crontab -e:

```
*/1 * * * * /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/scripts/test.sh
```

This file `test.sh` should be executed every minute. But it doesn't work.

If I run the script manually it works fine. So I think the problem is the cronjob not the script ;)

Are there any permissions or something else which block the cronjob?

Is the cronjob syntax correct?

Thx

Comment: your question is not a about programming

Comment: The problem is the script, not the cronjob.

Comment: This question is about programming.

Answer (score 4):

For a start, you don't need the `/1` if you want it done every minute. Just setting the minute field to `*` will do.

Next, you should place, as the *first* lines in your test script (though after the `#!` line if it's there):

```
env >/tmp/test.sh.dummy
set >>/tmp/test.sh.dummy
```

and see if that file shows up.

That will tell you if the script is running or not.

If it's *not* running, check to make sure `cron` itself is running:

```
pax> ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep
root      1048     1  0 08:45 ?        00:00:00 cron
```

(mine is).

If it *is* running, the most likely problem is that the environment under which `cron` runs your jobs is nowhere near the environment your shell gives you. Examine the differences between what was output to your `/tmp/test.sh.dummy` file and what your shell gives your when you execute `env ; set`.