# Another RPi idiot who can't understand cron

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi

Me big dum nooby, no grok cron, pleez you fix brain.

From the pi home directory, I type:

```
crontab -e
```

And at the bottom of the file I add a line:

```
*/5 * * * * date "+(0 6) %H:%M %Z" >> /home/pi/scripts/scripts.log
```

according to instructions I've read elsewhere while thrashing about on the Web; which I take to mean that every five minutes the system date will be printed to scripts.log.  I did add a blank line after this, saved and exited nano, and got the message "crontab: installing new crontab".

I waited, and nothing happened.  I went into `raspi-config`, set the time zone, and rebooted, though that shouldn't matter since it's supposed to run every 5 minutes, not at a specific time.  Yes, I created a scripts directory... after the third try... but still nothing.  No output at the command line, nothing in the scripts directory, no error messages.

Sorry to rehash what's been covered before, but the threads I've read are all in the context of some specific project, and I don't know enough yet to separate out the info I'm looking for.  I just want something, anything, to work using cron, then I'll think about the next thing to screw up.

My abject gratitude and a hollow promise to buy you a beer.

EDIT:  Thanks for the referral to another thread, but now I'm confused even more.  What script am I supposed to be running?  Do commands have to be part of some file, rather than executed directly as if they're typed on the command line?  (I hope that makes sense.)  Are the lines that start with `env >/tmp/test.sh.dummy` supposed to be in the script file with the date command, or part of the crontab file?

EDIT 2:  OK, so I've RTFM'ed on the Web for several hours, and now I understand that cron only runs scripts.  I was laboring under the assumption that it was a sort of "batch file," where commands would be as they would be typed at the command line and executed in the same way.

Let's forget the damn "date" thing, I just want to get this to work at all.  I've typed on the command line:

```
echo "This is a test."
```

That worked just as I expected.  Then I created a shell file, in the scripts directory in the pi directory, called firstscript.sh.  It reads as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is a test."
```

On the command line, I typed:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/scripts/firstscript.sh
```

In the cron table, I've entered the line:

```
* */2 * * * /home/pi/scripts/firstscript.sh
```

...With a carriage-return at the end.  This is after all the commented lines.  There was no `#!` (hashbang?) at the beginning of the file, so I did not add one.  Saved this, got the response `crontab: installing new crontab.`

If I understand this correctly, it should run every two minutes.  Waited 10 minutes.  Rebooted, waited another 10.  Tried the same, with the command in the crontab line changed to just `./firstscript.sh`.  Bupkus.

Forgive the long-windedness of this, I just don't know enough about what's going on to know which details are relevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux cronjob doesn't work (execute script)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483115/linux-cronjob-doesnt-work-execute-script)

Comment: You've been misinformed. cron can run any command that you can run from the command line; it doesn't have to be a script. Running the `date` command should work just fine. It runs the command in a restricted environment, including a basic `$PATH` that probably doesn't include, for example, `$HOME/bin` -- but that doesn't matter for the `date` command. Either the `cron` daemon isn't running, or there's a problem redirecting the output, or your system has a `date` command that doesn't support that option.

Comment: Does the `/home/pi/scripts` directory exist? What happens if you type `date "+(0 6) %H:%M %Z" >> /home/pi/scripts/scripts.log` from a shell prompt?

Comment: Yes, /home/pi/scripts exists, once I figured out to create it.  I've also learned (a bit) about redirecting output, and have finally gotten some results, if not the ones I expected.  It does seem to have to do with paths, where cron is running from versus where I am when I do things from the command line.  I just have to get the hang of this.  Thanks for your suggestions.  I'm going to switch over to the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange, as that's more my league.

Comment: The line `* */2 * * * /home/pi/scripts/firstscript.sh` in your edit appears that this would run every *two hours*, not every two minutes. (Also the first asterisk was interpreted as a bullet within your post).

Comment: Code samples need to be indented by 4 columns so the markdown processor can format them correctly. Or you can highlight it and click the `{}` icon.

Comment: If one of the posted answers solved the problem you asked about, consider accepting it by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

Me big dum ekspurt, pleez me fix own brain.

I just figured out what the problem is. I've even seen this before, and I really should have recognized this problem when I saw it again.

Quoting the `crontab(5)` man page:

> Percent-signs (`%`) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (`\`),
>   will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first
>   `%` will be sent to the command as standard input.

The `%` characters in the arguments to the `date` command are being intercepted by the `cron` daemon, and changed into newlines. This is creating an invalid command. You need to change this:

```
*/5 * * * * date "+(0 6) %H:%M %Z" >> /home/pi/scripts/scripts.log
```

to this:

```
*/5 * * * * date "+(0 6) \%H:\%M \%Z" >> /home/pi/scripts/scripts.log
```

and it should work.

As I mentioned previously in comments, the command in a `crontab` line does *not* need to be a shell script. It can be any command that you can execute from a shell prompt, except that it's run in a restricted environment. But in some cases, including this one, you have to be aware that `cron` will process the command itself before passing it on to `/bin/sh` to be executed.

Replacing the `date` command by a shell script that does the same thing would have worked (as long as the script name doesn't include any `%` characters), but it's not necessary.

Comment: Okay, I've tried getting help in the Raspberry Pi forum, but couldn't get any, so let me try again here.  Forget the date-command thing.  That was only trying to get something, anything to work with cron.  I do not want to run the date command from cron, or anywhere at all.  I want cron to run a Python script on a periodic basis.  I do not understand how to get this to happen.  If a person were to do this on a Raspberry Pi, what are the steps to go through to accomplish this?  Please understand that I have been able to master the cd and ls commands, and that's my entire expertise with Linux.

Comment: @eluhnabroad: I can only answer the question you asked. The question you asked here was about using cron with the `date` command, and I've answered that. [The question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/30025) you posted on the Raspberry Pi site is specifically not about cron. If you need help with `Twython.upload_media` (which you haven't mentioned here), post a new question about that. Comments are not the place to ask and answer new questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can Google the following steps:

1. Create a shell script.
2. Make sure the script has an appropriate hashbang on the first line.
3. Mark the script executable.
4. Try executing it on the command line.
5. If it works, add it to your crontab.

---

**EDIT:**  
I have tested and confirmed the OP's findings. I have also tested and confirmed my method shown above.

---

**OP's Method:**  
Add command to crontab:  
[image: OP-1]
Produces no results:  
[image: OP-2]

---

**Method listed above:**  
1. Create a shell script.  
2. Make sure the script has an appropriate hashbang on the first line.  
[image: ME-1]  
3. Mark the script executable.  
[image: ME-2]  
4. Try executing it on the command line. (It worked...)  
5. If it works, add it to your crontab.  
[image: ME-3]  
And the results were as expected:  
[image: ME-4]

Comment: Why would you expect an executable shell script to work when the `date` command doesn't? When I copy-and-paste the command `date "+(0 6) %H:%M %Z"` and run it on my system, it works correctly.

Comment: @KeithThompson  Thanks for your comment. I don't know the explanation for why this is (maybe someone with more knowledge will post it), but please see me edits above. Thanks.

Comment: Screen capture images are *much* less useful than copy-and-pasted text. I can't even read that  yellow on white text. Is the `date` command in the default `$PATH` used for cron jobs? The cron job runs every 5 minutes; did you wait long enough for it to run?

Comment: I know *I* waited a sufficient amount of time for this test. I can't speak for the OP. I used screenshots to show live results from a `Raspberry Pi` with the default system configuration.

Comment: The problem is the `%` characters, something that I definitely should have seen sooner. See my answer. (Using a script rather than invoking `date` directly actually would have fixed the problem, but it's not necessary.)